# Connection between maximal tori and roots

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, root-systems

I've been studying algebraic groups and there is a confusion that I have been unable to resolve.

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group and $T\subset G$ a maximal torus. If we let $T$ act on ${\rm Lie}(G)$ via the adjoint action we can see that $\mathfrak{g}$ decomposes into the direct sum of eigenspaces.

My question is this:

> Are the roots of $G$ with respect to $T$ equal to the non trivial characters of $T$ which are also eigenvalues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The answer is “almost”. The action of $T$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ decomposes the Lie algebra into weight spaces, I.e subspaces where $T$ acts via a character. Almost all of these are one-dimensional subspaces, corresponding to roots. There is a 0 weight space corresponding to the Cartan subalgebra.

Comment: Thank you @Joppy I think I understand better now. If I understand you correctly, there is a correspondence between the non trivial characters of $T$ and the non $0$ weight spaces (which themselves correspond to roots). If I changed my question to specify non trivial eigenvalues would it then be true?